# Multiple vulnerabilities when running "npx create-react-app"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

Every time I'm creating a new React app using the "npx create-react-app"-command I get multiple vulnerabilities (moderate and high) and I don't like it.

[Command log (using Git Bash)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFBIM.png)

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10929#issuecomment-873126693

Comment: update your `create-react-app` package. if there are vulns even after that do `npm audit`

Comment: Updating the create-react-app package didn't change a thing and "npm audit fix --force" seems to have made things worse.